# How can I prove $2^n+10n^2 \le 12 \cdot 2^n, n \ge 1$ is true by induction?

Tags: solution-verification, induction

I'm having trouble with this problem.
$2^n+10n^2 \le 12 \cdot 2^n, n \ge 1$

Here is my process.

n = 1, it is true <-- basis step

Assume that arbitrary k is true. $2^k+10k^2 \le 12 \cdot 2^k$.
And I make  $2^{k+1}+20(k)^2 \le 12 \cdot 2^{k+1}$ by multiplying 2.

But if k become k+1,the equation should be $2^{k+1}+10(k+1)^2 \le 12 \cdot 2^{k+1}$..
I can't translate $20k^2$ into $10(k+1)^2$. How can I prove it by induction?
Or is this equation false?

Comment: @Forester it should be $10n^2 \leq 11.2^n$

Comment: @Axel Yes. sorry

Comment: For $n=3$ it is false. Better say $2^n+10n^2 \le 12 \cdot 2^n, n> 3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Base case** : $2+10 \leqslant 24$ and $4 + 10 \cdot4 \leqslant 12 \cdot 2^2$ and $8+10 \cdot 9 \leq 12 \cdot 8$ so it's ok for $n\in \{1,2,3\}$.

**Inductive step** :

Let's suppose it's true for some $n\geqslant 3$.

Then $2^{n+1} + 10 (n+1)^2 = 2.2^n + 10 n^2 + 10(2n+1)$

$\leqslant 2 (12.2^n - 10 n^2) + 10 n^2 + 10(2n+1)$

$\leqslant 12.2^{n+1} - 10 n^2 + 10(2n+1)$

and this last expression is $\leqslant 12.2^{n+1}$ since $10 n^2 \geqslant 10 (2n+1)$ for $n\geqslant 3$ (you can easily prove that by induction).

Comment: $10n^2 \geq 10(2n+1)$ is false for $n \in \{1,2\}$

Comment: Thank you. I edited

Comment: Thank you! I undersood it!

Answer (score 1):

$ k^2 > 2k+1 \forall k>2$

$2k^2 > (k+1)^2$
$\Rightarrow 10(k+1)^2 < 20k^2$
$2^{k+1} + 10(k + 1)^2 < 2^{k+1} + 20k^2$

Answer (score 1):

We can use

$10n^2 - 20n - 10 = 10 [(n-1)^2 - 2] \gt 0$ for $n \gt 2$

i.e $20n^2 \gt  10n^2 + 20n + 10 \implies 10n^2 \gt  \frac{1}{2} (10n^2 + 20n + 10)$

We have $2^n+10n^2 \le 12 \times 2^n$

and we need to show $2^{n+1}+10(n+1)^2 \le 12 \times 2^{n+1}$

$2^{n+1}+10(n+1)^2 = 2 [2^n + \frac{1}{2}(10n^2 + 20n + 10)] \lt 2(2^n + 10n^2)$

i.e $2^{n+1}+10(n+1)^2 \leq 12 \times 2^{n+1}$

Comment: Thank you! I understood it.

Answer (score 1):

$2^n+10n^2 \le 12 \cdot 2^n, n \ge 4^{**}$

Divide both sides by $2^n$
$$1+\frac{10 n^2}{2^n}\le 12;\;n\ge 4\tag{1}$$
For $n=4$ it is true
$$1+\frac{10\cdot 4^2}{2^4}=11\le 12$$
Now suppose $(1)$  is true for $n$ and let's prove it for $n+1$
$$1+\frac{10 (n+1)^2}{2^{n+1}}=1+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{10n^2}{2^n}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{20n+10^*}{2^n}\right) <1+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{10n^2}{2^n}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{10n^2}{2^n}\right)=\\=1+\frac{10n^2}{2^n}\le 12$$
$^*\quad 20n+10<10n^2$ for $n\ge 4$

---

$^{**}$ inequality is false for $n=3$

indeed
$$2^3+10\cdot 3^2 \le 12 \cdot 2^3\to 98\le 96$$
which is false